# How to turn off the Camera in SimpleCV using python

Tags: python-2.7, simplecv

I am getting the following error when I run the code below:

> Error: Camera instance has no attribute 'release'

```
from SimpleCV import *
import time
def camera(self):
    try:
        cam=Camera(0)
                while cam is not None:
                    try:
                        img = cam.getImage()
                        img.show()
                        time.sleep(0.1)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cam.release()
        del cam
```

Any suggestions how to correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, looking at the documentation/source, it doesn't look like `release()` is an attribute (i.e. a method) inside the class Camera of SimpleCV, (as the error suggests,) so you're trying to call something that doesn't exist. I would guess that you could omit the line `cam.release()` since `del cam` already calls the destructor `__del__` which closes the camera for you.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. 
Documentation: https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/blob/master/SimpleCV/Camera.py

So just:

```
finally:
    del cam
```

PS: I would have just posted a comment but I'm a new user with no rep :)

Comment: I have used only del cam in finally  but it not turn off the camera @Leo R

Answer (score 0):

You cannot turn off the Camera using SimpleCv. To overcome this issue use OpenCV in that we can turn off the camera.